# Finding connected components of unconnected subset

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I found that the subset of $\mathbb R^2$:
$$S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: xy=1\}$$
is unconnected as you can take the surjective continuous function $f(x,y) =\begin{cases}1 & x>0\\ 0 & x<0 \\ \end{cases}$ to map onto $\{0,1\}$

I wanted to find the connected components but I have no idea where to start, I have the definition that a connected component is a maximal subset of topological space that cannot be covered by union of two disjoint open sets but this isn't really helping me, any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: How many components do you think this has? You might try graphing the equation $xy=1.$

Comment: @AdityaEkbote thank you, I'm just struggling with coming up with any potential ideas to test? I'm not completely confident in this and so don't know what kind of subsets I should be taking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph on Desmos shows the following [[image: Graph of <span class=]$y = \frac{1}{x}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh4x6.png)

As you can see it is the union of $(\frac{1}{x} \mid x > 0)$ and $(\frac{1}{x} \mid x < 0)$ so it is disconnected (If a space $x$ is connected the number of connected components is $1$ and it is the whole space $X$ itself)

Now here is a lemma,

> $(0, \infty)$ is connected in $\mathrm{R}$
> (Try to prove this)

Now there are two such connected sets which make up for your set $S$ which are the component